# Ember addon: Could not find module from within component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon, ember-cli-addons

In a new ember 3.28 *addon* project:

```
npm install chart.js --save
ember g component-class chart
```

Insert `<Chart />` into application.hbs on dummy app and in addons/component/chart.js, add this

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

Running app gives:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `chart.js/auto` imported from `chartjs-test/components/chart`
```

Yet if the `import Chart` goes into the application.js route in the dummy app instead, it works.  How can you import this module correctly from within an addon component?

**Update:** Same issue with other installed packages eg. `import chroma from "chroma";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need to add the same import statement into app/component/chart.js:

**UPDATE:**
The above isn't the proper way and causes issues when using the addon elsewhere.  The real solution is to move ember-auto-import to dependencies from devDependencies in package.json of the addon